# Emacs Starter Kit on the Mac

Tags: emacs

I just installed Emacs on my mac from here:
http://emacsformacosx.com/
and that got rid of all the menus. How do I get those menus back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for **menu-bar-mode** in your `~/.emacs`  or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

You should find...

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
```

If so, remove it. If you don't find it... add the following line.

```
(menu-bar-mode 1)
```

and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable or disable the menu in emacs, you can use

```
M-x menu-bar-mode
```

and if you want the same with the toolbar you can use

```
M-x tool-bar-mode
```

The menu should be enabled "by default" unless stated otherwise in your .emacs file which you can find in emacs using `C-x C-f ~/.emacs`.

Comment: emacs config could also be in ~/.emacs.d/init.el